# Generate 100 million records between 2 ranges and insert

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a request to develop an inventory system for a warehouse that deals in airtime recharge cards. Per the requirement they can load serial numbers into the database which can be a minimum of about 100 million individual records. I need to get a function that can accept two strings and use that to generate the individual records within that range as below. But I know this is not an effective way of generation and insertion into the database, kindly help

```
startserial : 99092110000000
endserial   : 99092119999999
```

Code:

```
Private Sub Scanin(startserial As String, Endserial As String)
    Dim serialnum As Decimal : Dim qry As String

    serialnum = CDec(startserial)

    For inc As Decimal = serialnum To CDec(Endserial)
        qry = "Insert into BatchTemp(SerialNumber) VALUES (@a)"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", serialnum)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        serialnum += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What you want is called a Tally. There are plenty of examples on how to create these out there.

Comment: Thank you Larnu, can you please provide me some links

Comment: "SQL Server Tally Table" -> [Google.com](http://google.com)

Comment: don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Larnu, I found one but after using I get an error `The value 100000000 specified for the MAXRECURSION option exceeds the allowed maximum of 32767.`

Comment: See also [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/12/t-sql-queries/number-series-challenge) for probably the best examples available, by Itzik Ben-Gan

Comment: @Larnu, please help me out with my perculiar issue using the Tally, am new to it. How I can enter a range to generate the records

Comment: Good link to recent discussion from itzik - esp. if 100million values are needed **quickly** (though 30 secs is still pretty short for the worst case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, use a Tally. Don't use an rCTE to do this, they are incredibly slow (as I show [here](https://wp.larnu.uk/speed-test-rcte-vs-tally/)), use a set based method with `ROW_NUMBER`. @CharlieFace also provided you a link on how to create a tally in their comment, to an [article](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/12/t-sql-queries/number-series-challenge) by Itzik Ben-Gan.

In short, if you need to define the start and end values, then this would need little change, apart from a `TOP` and some basic addition. For a tally made up of up to 10,000 rows, I would write it something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @Start int = 700,
        @End int = 9874;

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (@End - @Start +1)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + @Start - 1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4) --10,000 rows
SELECT I
FROM Tally;
```

If you need more rows, then just add more cross joins to `N` in the CTE Tally. (Though for 100M, you may well be better off doing 10M batches.)